# What chain complex is denoted by a single $R$?

Tags: homological-algebra

I was reading about Koszul Complex and I am fairly new to the topic. So lemme start with a ring $R$, not necesarilly commutative and let $x\in R$ be central.

Denote $K(x)$ to be the chain complex $0\to R\to R \to 0$ and the map from $R$ to $R$ is just multiplying by $x$.

I was reading a proof which starts with:

Considering the following natural SES of chain complexes $$0\to R\to K(x)\to R[-1]\to 0$$

I was wondering what complex is denoted by $R$ alone?

I thought about a couple possibilities but none seem to give a SES of chain complexes. For instance, I thought about $\cdots\to R\to R\to \cdots$ where morphisms are just identity ones but that does not give a SES.

I couldn't seem to find any more background on this matter in the notes but if it is the preferred to post the entire proof, I will try to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe $\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the complex which has just an $R$ term in degree $0$. Hence with homological grading the degree $0$ SES looks like
$$0\to R\to R\to 0\to 0$$
and degree $-1$ looks like
$$0\to 0\to R\to R\to 0$$
which are both exact.
At any other degree you just get a SES of zeroes.